# Is there a way to only activate a button on mouse starts click

Tags: unity-game-engine

I imagine a click and hold like this:
[image]

Is there a way to make a button activate only if it's in it's start click phase?

Comment: From what I understand you want the button deactivated during the hold phase, right? I recommend checking the Input.GetMouseButton and Input.GetMouseButtonDown explanations in Unity's [Script Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Input.GetMouseButton` (it returns true while the mouse button is pressed) and a timer. Your code would only be triggered if `Input.GetMouseButton` returns true and `timer` is greater than some amount of time, and use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` (it returns true on the frame where mouse button was pressed) to grab the current time. Code will look like this:

Obs.: i converted `Time.time` to int to make it more similar to seconds, but you can remove it just by deleting the `(int)` before and it will be reverted to float.

```
float timer;
float timeLimit;
public float waitTime = 1; //amount of seconds that user will have to wait before code is executed

if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) timeLimit = (int)(Time.time) + waitTime; //called only once

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){ //called while lmb is held down
   timer = (int)(Time.time);
   if(timer >= timeLimit){
       //Your code here
   }
}
```